# How To Check if elapsed Time Has Passed By 30 minutes For the process

Tags: macos, shell, ps

i am trying to kill those process which has elapse time greater than 30 minutes .  First i tried getting all the pid of tomcat and looping through it to find the elapsed time.

I tried implementing following code to check if IF Condition is working fine

```
OUTPUT=$(ps |grep tomcat|awk '{print $1}')
OUTPUTARRAY=(${OUTPUT})
for i in "${OUTPUTARRAY[@]}"
do
     etime=$(ps -p $i -o etime |awk '{print $1}')
     echo $etime
     elapsedArray=(${etime})
     elapsed=${elapsedArray[1]}
     if [ $elapsed > "30:00" ]
     then
        echo ${elapsed}
     fi
done
```

it is always getting into if condition no matter what the time is

Comment: You're comparing strings with the `>` operator, it doesn't make sense

Comment: Your Comment is not helping , i am new to shell , help me out how to compare the String .

Comment: Using the output of 'ps .. -oetime' may be risky. The actual format for elapsed time will vary depending on the value. It can include hours (1:23:45), days (4-02:12:23), etc. Only for very small values it will use the 'HH:MM' format.

Comment: Consider using 'set -x' at the top of your script - this will give you some insight into the result of each step (more specific, the values of 'elapsed', 'etime'). You might get more feedback if you post the output with specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using 'etimes' instead of 'etime'. The 'etimes' value is numeric, in seconds, make it easier to compare. Also add trailing '=' to etimes to strip the header (ELAPSED).

```
# Inside the for loop:
etimes=$(ps -p "$i" -o etimes=)
if [ "$elapsed" -gt $((30*60)) ] ; then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: If you are using arithmetic expansion, it's just easier to `if (( elapsed > 30*60 ))`

Comment: in mac , it is showing etimes command not found
"ps: etimes: keyword not found"